# Arc length of $y=\frac12(x^2+2)^{\frac32}$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

> Determine the arc length of the curve
>   $$y=\frac12(x^2+2)^{\frac32},\ 0\le x\le2$$

I have tried doing this and reached the point:
$$L=\frac32 \int_0^2 \sqrt{(x^2+1)^2-\frac59}\ dx$$

Now I'm stuck, and I've tried using conjugates and substitution without success.

Comment: Integrating, you will get elliptic functions. Are you sure you have the right function? In general, lenths of curves will give non-elementary functions. It is just a few exceptions that give elementary functions. Did you write your exercise correctly?

Comment: Hi mickep, It is one of our quizzes that we were given under Arc length topic and we have dealt with elliptic functions all the way to trigonometry and hyperbolic functions.
I have checked again and it is the correct function. We were given the answer in numeric form being 7.7883.
I have used Wolfram and matlab and they result in complex solutions whose magnitude gives 6.495.

Comment: I totally agree with  mickep's comment. This is avery difficult integral; I confirm that the correct value is $6.49485$.

Comment: Even though I believe the OP, I just can't resist. Replace the $1/2$ upfront with $1/3$ and then it comes out beautifully. Elliptical functions are nice as an answer except that if you have to use the outcome of the arclength in some (engineering) application, you will still toggle it into the calculator to see what the answer looks like, as Claude has done...